# Distinct 2 columns with Summary

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have a table with 2 staff columns and 3 type of statuses. How I can count all statuses on distinct of 2 columns of staff. Thank you.

**My table:**

| staff1 | staff2 | status1 | status2 | status3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Joseph | ACTIVE | CLOSED |  |
| Kevin | Nicole | NA | ACTIVE | CLOSED |
| Nicole | Kevin |  | CLOSED | ACTIVE |

**Result:**

| STAFF | ACTIVE | CLOSED | NA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Kevin | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Nicole | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Joseph | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I tried following but it never distinct of staff:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN staff1 = staff2 THEN staff1
    WHEN staff1 <> staff2 THEN staff1
    WHEN staff2 <> staff1 THEN staff2
    ELSE staff2 AS staffall,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status1 = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0)
    SUM(CASE WHEN status1 = 'CLOSED' THEN 1 ELSE 0)
    SUM(CASE WHEN status1 = 'NA' THEN 1 ELSE 0)
FROM Table
GROUP BY staff1, staff2
```

Comment: Unpivot your denormalised columns first, then aggregate.

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: Probably the first thing you should do is to change your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to define a set of distinct staff in a CTE first and then join that to your table:

```
with StaffDistinct(Staff) as (
select staff1
from StaffStatus
union
select staff2
from StaffStatus
)

select  sd.Staff,
        sum(case when Status1='ACTIVE' or Status2='ACTIVE' or Status3='ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) as ACTIVE,
        sum(case when Status1='CLOSED' or Status2='CLOSED' or Status3='CLOSED' then 1 else 0 end) as CLOSED,
        sum(case when Status1='NA' or Status2='NA' or Status3='NA' then 1 else 0 end) as NA
from    StaffDistinct sd
join    StaffStatus ss on sd.Staff = ss.Staff1 or sd.Staff = ss.Staff2
group by sd.staff;
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e603a/1)

Answer (score 0):

Just another option

**Example**

```
;with cte as ( 
Select Staff=staff1,status1,status2,status3 from YourTable
Union All
Select Staff=staff2,status1,status2,status3 from YourTable
)
Select Staff
      ,Active = sum(case when Value='Active' then 1 else 0 end)
      ,Closed = sum(case when Value='Closed' then 1 else 0 end)
      ,NA     = sum(case when Value='NA'     then 1 else 0 end)
 From (
        Select *
         From  cte
         Unpivot ( Value for [ColName] in ([Status1],[Status2],[Status3]) ) U 
      ) A
 Group By Staff
```

**Results**

```
Staff   Active  Closed  NA
John    1       1       0
Joseph  1       1       0
Kevin   2       2       1
Nicole  2       2       1
```

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
select staffAll
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN status1 = 'ACTIVE' or status2 = 'ACTIVE' or status3 = 'ACTIVE' 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) Active
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN status1 = 'CLOSED' or status2 = 'CLOSED' or status3 = 'CLOSED' 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) Closed
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN status1 = 'NA' or status2 = 'NA' or status3 = 'NA' 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) NA
FROM (
  SELECT staff1 staffAll,status1,status2,status3 from MyTable
  Union All
  SELECT staff2 staffAll,status1,status2,status3 from MyTable
   )t
GROUP BY staffall
```

Answer (score 0):

..maybe to consolidate all staff and statuses and then PIVOT using the status col. as an aggregate/spreading element..

**Example**

```
--add test data
drop table if exists dbo.Staff_status;
go
create table dbo.Staff_status (staff1 varchar(255),
                           staff2 varchar(255),
                           status1 varchar(32),
                           status2 varchar(32),
                           status3 varchar(32)
)
go

insert into dbo.Staff_status
   select *
   from (values  ('John','Joseph','ACTIVE','CLOSED',''),
                 ('Kevin','Nicole','NA','ACTIVE','CLOSED'),
                 ('Nicole','Kevin','','CLOSED','ACTIVE')
        ) as tab(a,b,c,d,e)
go

select *
from dbo.Staff_status;

;with Staff as
(
    select staff1 as staff,
           status1,
           status2,
           status3
    from dbo.Staff_status
    union all
    select staff2 as staff,
           status1,
           status2,
           status3
    from dbo.Staff_status
),status1 as
(
    select staff,
           status = status1
    from Staff
    union all
    select staff,
           status = status2
    from Staff
    union all
    select staff,
           status = status3
    from Staff
)
    select pvt.staff,
           pvt.[ACTIVE],
           pvt.[CLOSED],
           pvt.[NA]
    from status1
    PIVOT (
            COUNT(status)
            FOR status IN ([ACTIVE],[CLOSED],[NA])
    ) as pvt
```

**RESULTS**

| staff1 | staff2 | status1 | status2 | status3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Joseph | ACTIVE | CLOSED |  |
| Kevin | Nicole | NA | ACTIVE | CLOSED |
| Nicole | Kevin |  | CLOSED | ACTIVE |

(RESULT)

| staff | ACTIVE | CLOSED | NA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Joseph | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Kevin | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Nicole | 2 | 2 | 1 |